# Regex back-reference replace oddity

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following snippet:

```
var escapedBlock = Regex.Escape(retString);
var escapedSearch = Regex.Escape(searchText);

string highlightedString = Regex.Replace(escapedBlock, "(" + escapedSearch + ")", Regex.Escape("<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>") + "$1" + Regex.Escape("</span>"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return Regex.Unescape(highlightedString);
```

Which takes a block of text (`retString`) and returns a highlighted string based on the argument that you pass to it (`searchText`). I'm using a backreference to the first matched group to make sure capitalization of the match persists into the highlighted text that's returned.

This has worked swimmingly except for one scenario: A number followed by a period.

`.5   - works`
`5    - works`
`test - works`
`5.   - broken`

While searching for `.5` works fine, searching for `6.5` does not -- the `Replace` method doesn't seem to make a match at all.

My initial suspect was something having to do with escaping the actual result of the value of whatever the back-reference (`$1`) was, but if I directly escape the back-reference I end up getting a bunch of errors on invalid escape characters.

What am I missing here?

Comment: That is because you add a literal ``\`` before a dot when escaping the *input* string. Why escape at all? I think you need to remove `var escapedBlock = Regex.Escape(retString);`  and apply the regex replace  on just `retString` and return `highlightedString` without unescaping.

Comment: A lot of escaping going on there. When using a _literal_ as a regular expressions, you only need to escape the literal. In this case, the  `escapedSearch` . And don't do any of the other escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a literal `\` before a dot when escaping the *input* string and a `5\.` pattern only matches `5.`, not `5\.`. You need to remove `var escapedBlock = Regex.Escape(retString);`  and apply the `Regex.Replace` on `retString` and return `highlightedString` without unescaping.

Use

```
var escapedSearch = Regex.Escape(searchText);
var highlightedString = Regex.Replace(retString, escapedSearch,
    "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>$&</span>"),
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return highlightedString;
```

Note you need no capturing group to access the whole match value, you may use the `$&` backreference.